# is there any way to dynamically convert the English API response received through Retrofit to any other language?

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a Quotes App, using an  API to call the quotes, using retrofit, and now I want the app to have the option of translating all to Portuguese, Spanish and English. I’m new at coding can someone please help me?, how can I do that?

(The language of my app is #Kotlin)

Comment: i'm doubtful if this would be possible without the use of another api, perhaps it would make life simpler to just find an api which can support this for you

Comment: do you mean finding an API with every different idiom? i didn't get it.

Comment: i'm suggesting that you try to find a different quote api, one where you can pass a language to it so that it gives you the translated quote back already, then there's no need for you to translate it

Comment: ok, i got it!, thank you, but if i wanted the API to have more than just one option of language, for the user to choose? would that be possible using quotes by an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no way of requesting different language versions of the quotes, your best bet is to use a third-party API to do the translation.

This might be more than you want to tackle, but Google does have an ML kit to provide text translation: [Translate text with ML Kit on Android](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation/android)

I've never used it, but it doesn't seem too difficult for basic text translation to a few languages.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something that can be done directly.
I guess the best approach to achieve that functionality would be using a second API for translating the result of the query from the first API.

Just Google "Translation API".